# How to target CSS class names that start with digit

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list class that I want apply a top margin to - but it seems like the syntax is invalid with CSS. I don't think it likes the `1200mm-x-4700mm` section.

I cannot rename the list class as it is automatically generated. Is there any way around this to allow me to apply the CSS styling?

```html
<li class="max-panel-size 1200mm-x-4700mm">...</li>
```

```css
li.max-panel-size.1200mm-x-4700mm {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML5, CSS class names can contain (and start with) just about any character. However, in order to target fancy CSS class names inside CSS files (or JavaScript functions) [**you need to escape them**](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#cssescapes).

```css
li.max-panel-size.\31 200mm-x-4700mm {
  background: #F00;
}
li.max-panel-size.\31 111mm-x-1111mm {
  background: #0F0;
}
li.max-panel-size.\39 999mm-x-9999mm {
  background: #00F;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="max-panel-size 1200mm-x-4700mm">Test 1</li>
  <li class="max-panel-size 1111mm-x-1111mm">Test 2</li>
  <li class="max-panel-size 9999mm-x-9999mm">Test 3</li>
</ul>
```

You could use the [CSS2 `[att~=val]` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) as well.

Comment: BTW: HTML5 allows for numeric id and id starting with a number. But, CSS3 specs still don't say that and follows CSS2.1 convention of not allowing number prefixed names/id.

Answer (score 2):

You could set an attribute class to solve this issue:

```
[class*="1200mm-"] {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

This will style every class that contain `1200-m`

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/o9re6vf1/

Comment: [Classes shouldn't start with a digit...](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters)

Comment: @AndréDion Of course, but this is a sane way to overcome an issue like this.

Comment: Sane? It's just plain incorrect. Some browsers may allow it anyway, but it's a blatant violation of the CSS specification nonetheless.

Comment: @DarrenBaker said that "can't rename the list class as it's automatically generated." so this is a solution that solves this problem. I don't suggest in any way a classname that starts with a number since it's incorrect

Answer (score 1):

CSS Class selector and ID selector starting with a number is not valid.

- [Characters and case](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters)

But still you can work-around this. There is two way to achieve this

first is [`attribute`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) selector:

```
/* attribute selector */
[class="12px"] {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Other is [`unicode`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/refs.html#ref-UNICODE) selector:

```
/* or unicode selector */
.\31 00px {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```css
/* attribute selector */
[class="12px"] {
  font-size: 12px;
}

/* or unicode selector */
.\31 00px {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p class="12px"> Hello, world. </p>
<p class="100px"> Hello, world. </p>
```

> Note: If you are going use the attribute selector route, be aware that it only works down to IE7. If you need to support older browsers than that you have my sympathies (you can still use the unicode selectors).

Answer (score 0):

You can user defined HTML5 data-attributes

```
<li class="max-panel-size" data-margin="1200mm-x-4700mm">

li[data-margin="1200mm-x-4700mm"]{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```