# CSS class selectors not changing anything

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems with my CSS. It should set the colour of a div with a class (for a countdown), but the colour of the text isn't changing. I've tried numerous fixes,  but can't get it working. Here is the relevant CSS:

```
.10seconds, .9seconds, .8seconds, .7seconds, .6seconds { color: #00b200 ;}
.5seconds { color: #ADFF2F ;}
.4seconds { color: #E5E500 ;}
.3seconds { color: #FFA500 ;}
.2seconds { color: #FF5719 ;}
.1seconds { color: #FF0000;}
```

And the relevant HTML:

```
<div id='timer' class='10seconds'>10</div>
```

`#timer` has no set rules in my CSS file. Full [CSS here](http://readometer.co.uk/style.css).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: css can't start with a number?

Comment: CSS declaration cant start with a number, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016787/how-to-target-css-class-names-that-start-with-digit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your class names begin with number, which is not allowed in CSS. Revert the name and number, eg:

```css
.sec5{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="sec5"> 5 sec </div>
```

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors) it is well explained about CSS class names

Comment: I'll try this when I have chance, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Technically speaking, it is not that HTML classes cannot start with a digit. Rather, it is that `10seconds` is not a valid **CSS identifier**, which means that the CSS processor will choke on a rule such as

```
.10seconds { }
```

and ignore it. The solution, if you really want to use the `10seconds` class, is to escape the leading digit:

```
.\31 0seconds { }
```

The `\31` here is a the digit `1`, and the escape sequence "eats" the following space.

Another alternative is to write the rule using an attribute selector:

```
[class~="10seconds"] { color: #00b200; }
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors) (second answer):

If you want to use a class name which is not a valid CSS identifier in `querySelector`, you may use the [`CSS.escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape) utility if it is available on your platform:

```
document.querySelector('.' + CSS.escape('10seconds'))
```

> ...most answers here are wrong. It turns out that any character except NUL is allowed as CSS class name in CSS.

Of course, as other answers suggest, you may prefer to simply use valid CSS identifiers as class names, such as `seconds10`, and avoid all this trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is you are using time parameter as a class name instead you can use below format

```css
.seconds10, .seconds9, .seconds8, .seconds7, .seconds6 { color: #00b200 ;}
.seconds4 { color: #E5E500 ;}
.seconds3 { color: #FFA500 ;}
.seconds2 { color: #FF5719 ;}
.seconds1 { color: #FF0000;}
```

```html
<div id='timer' class='seconds10'>10</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.myClass {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">This header should be GREEN to match the class selector 5 sec</div>
```